# How to order by many to many relationship in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship between **User** and **Category** through **UserCategory** as below.

```
let user = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    id: req.query.user
  },
  attributes: ["id", "name"],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Category,
      as: "interests",
      attributes: ["id", "name", "nameTH", "icon"],
      through: {
        model: models.UserCategory,
        as: "user_categories",
        attributes: ["id", "userId", "categoryId", "updatedAt"]
      }
    }
  ],
  // Here, I want to order by updatedAt in user_categories
  order: [["user_categories", "updatedAt", "DESC"]] 
});
```

> How can I order the result by "updatedAt" inside **UserCategory** model?

Comment: What is your sequelize version?

Comment: "sequelize": "^5.21.3", "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer the following code to sort the result by `updatedAt` inside `UserCategory` model-

```
let user = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    id: req.query.user
  },
  attributes: ["id", "name"],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Category,
      as: "interests",
      attributes: ["id", "name", "nameTH", "icon"],
      through: {
        model: models.UserCategory,
        as: "user_categories",
        attributes: ["id", "userId", "categoryId", "updatedAt"]
      }
    }
  ],
  // Here, I want to order by updatedAt in user_categories
  order: [[Sequelize.literal('`interests->user_categories`.`updatedAt`'), 'DESC']] 
});
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: You save my life again! Thanks for your time. @SohamLawar

Comment: Amazing! Good call.

Comment: I have this error: syntax error (approximate position: \ ". \") (translated from google). Can you help me with this?

Comment: Solved, answer below :)

Answer (score 3):

For **those** who have error like this: 
`ошибка синтаксиса (примерное положение: \".\")`
or
`syntax error (approximate position: \ ". \")`

1. Go to `Sequelize.literal()` function
2. Change the argument string from **single quotes ('')** to **double quotes ("")**
3. Then, just swap **backticks ( `` )** and **double quotes ("")**

```
let user = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    id: req.query.user
  },
  attributes: ["id", "name"],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Category,
      as: "interests",
      attributes: ["id", "name", "nameTH", "icon"],
      through: {
        model: models.UserCategory,
        as: "user_categories",
        attributes: ["id", "userId", "categoryId", "updatedAt"]
      }
    }
  ],
  // Your changes here
  order: [[Sequelize.literal(`"interests->user_categories"."updatedAt"`), 'DESC']] 
  // order: [[Sequelize.literal('`interests->user_categories`.`updatedAt`'), 'DESC']] 
});
```

Special thanks to [@SohamLawar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4068817/soham-lawar)

Comment: Thank you for this update. It might be a SQL syntax thing for postgresql.

Comment: This was the perfect one!

Answer (score 2):

This solution is working for me with PostgreSQL. I'm able to add an order clause on the joining table.

```js
let user = await User.findAll({
  where: {
    id: req.query.user
  },
  attributes: ["id", "name"],
  include: [
    {
      model: models.Category,
      as: "interests",
      attributes: ["id", "name", "nameTH", "icon"],
      through: {
        model: models.UserCategory,
        as: "user_categories",
        attributes: ["id", "userId", "categoryId", "updatedAt"]
      }
    }
  ],
  // Your changes here
  order: [[{model: models.Category, as: 'interests'}, {model: models.UserCategory, as: 'user_categories'}, 'updatedAt',  'DESC']] 
});
```